# Modify user profile page, not login page

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to edit the user profile page, not the login page.

However, with Drupal 7, the template for the profile and the login page is the same.

I tried to modify page--user.tpl.php, but it also modifies the login page. And modify user--profile.tpl allow to modify the order of the fields but not the entire page.

Do you know how to do it ?

Comment: Maybe add another template suggestion for logged in users? And then have page--user--logged-in.tpl.php?

Comment: Yes I thought of this solution, but the template must be the same whether the user is logged in or not

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what that means. Can you maybe edit your question and add a little bit more info about what exactly it is you want to achieve in the end? And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For theming user profile page use `page--user--%.tpl.php` template file.

To see all possible template suggestions right in your code you can enable [Theme debug mode](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/overriding-themable-output/working-with-template-suggestions#theme-debug) in sites/default/settings.php:

```
$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;
```